# OrchardCMS: How to extract TextField data into a file?

Tags: c#, export, orchardcms

For the past few days I've been checking out OrchardCMS and right now I need to extract some data from the text boxes on my webpage outside into a file.

I made a simple form (Name, Surname, Email etc) as a CustomForm for testing purpose. I want what's written in these text fields to be exported into an external file (even a .txt is fine), preferably through c#. I can't find a way to connect c# and Orchard together properly (I can't even understand where I could write my own code in the Orchard website project)

My question is, what's a good way to export inputted data in the text fields of the form outside into a (text)file?

Comment: For new functionality you should at least start with creating a new module. When do you want it to export? When you save the item? When you click a dashboard button?

Comment: @devqon I want the export to happen when I click the submit button on the form. That's the desired trigger.

Comment: Then you can just create a content handler that catches the OnCreated or OnUpdated event of your custom content part, then write the content to a file. Your custom content part should be attached to the content types you want to be exported

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input. Will get on it.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is creating a new module which leverages a new custom part, 'ExportItemPart', and attach that to the contenttypes you want to have exported. Something like the following implementation will do (I don't include the actual converting to a file).

Models/ExportItemPart.cs:

```
public class ExportItemPart : ContentPart {}
```

Drivers/ExportItemPartDriver.cs:

```
public class ExportItemPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<ExportItemPart> {
    // doesn't do anything visual, just leave empty 
    // to be able to catch the handler events
}
```

Handlers/ExportItemPartHandler.cs:

```
public class ExportItemPartHandler {

    public ExportItemPartHandler(IExportService exportService) {

        // 'Catch' the OnCreated event of the ExportItemPart,
        // then export the item
        OnCreated<ExportItemPart>((ctx, part) => _exportService.ExportItem(part.ContentItem));
    }
}
```

Services/IExportService.cs:

```
// Inherit from IDependency to make use of DI
public interface IExportService : IDependency {
    void ExportItem(ContentItem contentItem);
}
```

Services/ExportService.cs:

```
public class ExportService : IExportService {
    public void ExportItem(ContentItem contentItem) {
        // Logic for exporting the item to a file
    }
}
```